# I want to implement two methods to check if a number is a palindrome

Tags: java, palindrome

As above, I have two methods,

```
public static int reverse(int number)
```

and

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(int number)
```

I should arrange them to check whether a number is palindrome or not. I tried to apply the hint (a number is palindrome if (its reversal == itself)) but it did not help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("This program checks whether a number is palindrome or not. Enter a number: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int inputNumber = input.nextInt();

        // if inputNumber is palindrome 

        System.out.println("The number is palindrome.");

        // else 

        System.out.println("The number is not a palindrome.");
    }


        public static int reverse(int number)

        // reverse number


        public static boolean isPalindrome(int number)

        // check if the number is palindrome     
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your code which you have tried?

Comment: "but it did not help" - why not? That is correct, so your reversal code was incorrect. Please show it

Comment: @q1612749 I have added solution. Please mark correct and upvote if it solved your problem. Also It will be better if you post your code.

Comment: Added my solution. Any comments?

Answer (score 2):

In order to reverse a number you should divide it by 10 and add the remainder to a new reversed number multiplied by 10.

For example, this will be the steps of reverting 123:

1. reversed = 0, target = 123
2. reversed = 0 * 10 + 123 % 10 = 0 + 3 = 3, target = 123 / 10 = 12
3. reversed = 3 * 10 + 12 % 10 = 30 + 2 = 32, target = 12 / 10 = 1
4. reversed = 32 * 10 + 1 % 10 = 320 + 1 = 321, target = 1 / 10 = 0

Here is implementation of this algorithm in Java:

```
public static int reverse(int number) {
    int reversed = 0;
    while (number > 0) {
        reversed *= 10;
        reversed += number % 10;
        number /= 10;
    }
    return reversed;
}

public static boolean isPalindrome(int number) {
    return number == reverse(number);
}
```

Comment: Added my solution. Any comments?

Comment: @q1612749 it's quite similar to mine except that your return statement could be simplified to `return n2 == reverse(n2)`. Concerning your 011 case - Java interpret 011 as octal digit (as it starts with 0) so the base10 value is 9 which is a palindrome

Answer (score 0):

Try this method for reverse.

```
Step0  : temp = 0 number  = 4554
Step 1 : temp = 4 number = 455
Step 2 : temp = 4*10 +  5 = 45 and number = 45
Step 3 : temp = 45*10 + 5 = 455 and number  = 4
Step 4 : temp = 455*10 + 4 = 4554 and number  = 0


    if (inputNumber == reverse(inputNumber)) {
        System.out.println("The number is palindrome.");
    }else{
        System.out.println("The number is not a palindrome.");
    }

public static int reverse(int number) {
    int temp = 0;
    while (number > 0) {
        temp = temp * 10 + number % 10;
        number = number / 10;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Don't answer to homework questions with just a plain code snippet. Instead at least provide explanation as Dmitry Smorzhok did.

Comment: Yes Thanks for downvoting.

Comment: This is not homework question. I am 23 (almost 24) and unemployed. I quit school long ago. I just want to know the solution to this problem.

Comment: Hey man @q1612749 , Don't think too much, people say many things here. You got your answer so get on. Also upvote my answer if you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter an integer: " );
        int inputNumber = input.nextInt();

        if (isPalindrome(inputNumber))
            System.out.println(inputNumber + " is a palindrome. ");
        else
            System.out.println(inputNumber + " is not a palindrome. ");

        input.close();
    }

    public static int reverse(int n1) {
        int reversedNumber = 0;
        while (n1 != 0) {
            reversedNumber *= 10;
            reversedNumber += (n1 % 10);
            n1 /= 10;
        }

        return reversedNumber;
    }

    public static boolean isPalindrome(int n2) {
        if (n2 == reverse(n2))
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }
}
```

This is a solution to the problem. But this does not cover the case in which I could enter "011" and the program will say that "11" is a palindrome. How could I solve this?

Comment: Insert that into your question. Don’t post questions as answers.

Answer (score 0):

The following algorithm will work

```
1. Loop until the input number become 0.

    1.1 remainder = number % 10;
    1.2 reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;
    1.3 number = number / 10;

2. Return reverse when the loop breaks. That means number became 0.
```

[Check full implementation here](https://www.tuturself.com/posts/view?menuId=89&postId=1005).